# openssl BN_mod_exp function results different output for same inputs on two executions

Tags: security, encryption, openssl, cryptography, rsa

I'm using openssl library in my project, I execute the program at the same time on two terminals with the same inputs. When they get to 
BN_mod_exp(temp1,temp2,Y,p,ctx); they result different outputs although inputs are the same values.

I print every BIGNUM value that the function inputs to make sure it's the same in both programs.

I saw there was a problem with this function on earlier versions of openssl, anyway I use the last version 1.0.2n

what could still make a different between the two executions?

Comment: The cause is almost certainly a bug in your program. That's why you're supposed to post [the code for a proper example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your bug/problem.

Comment: Please show your code. Since Stack Overflow hides the Close reason from you: *Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).*